# Nash equilibria vs. sub-game perfect NE in Stackelberg competition

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I'm reviewing game theory and came across these slides: http://www.econ.ohio-state.edu/jpeck/Econ601/Econ601L10.pdf.

On the last few pages it talks about Stackelberg Competition.

> Two firms set quantities just like in Cournot. Marginal production cost is equal to 100, and market inverse demand is given by p = 1000 − q1 − q2. Firm 1 moves first.

It goes on to derive the best response of Firm 1 and Firm 2. We get that the subgame perfect Nash equilibrium is (450, 225).

What I'm confused about is the last slide:

> Although the game has one SPNE, there are many NE that violate sequential rationality, for example:
>
> q1 = 64
>
> q2(q1) = 418 if q1 = 64
>
> q2(q1) = 1000 otherwise.

How is the above a NE? I understand that a set of strategies is NE if each player's action is the best response given the other player's action. But in this case why is Firm 1's quantity (64) a best response to Firm 2?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

A way to understand the difference between Nash equilibrium and subgame perfect equilibrium is the following. In a Nash equilibrium every party is playing a best reply (to others' actions) *on the equilibrium path*. In a subgame perfect equilibrium, every party is also (planning to) play a best reply *off the equilibrium path*.

In your example, consider Player 1. The equilibrium path has 1 playing 64 and 2 playing 418. As shown in the slides you mention, each party is playing a best reply. So it is a Nash equilibrium.

We get off the equilibrium path when 1 deviates. Suppose 1 plays $q_1 \ne 64$; f.i., he plays $q_1 = 50$. Then 2's best reply should be $q^*_2(50) = 425$ *whereas* her plan is to play $q_2 = 1000$. So she is not best replying to 1's possible deviations.